# Using Entity Framework to retrieve a group with subgroups each with their own subgroups

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am building a hierarchy of groups to represent an organisational structure. I have one top level group which then has a number of sub groups. Each sub group can then have any number of sub groups and so on.

I've set up a sql database with two tables.

Groups with the following columns.

- Id (int)
- Description (nvarchar(max))

GroupChildren with the following columns.

- Id (int)
- GroupId (int)
- ChildGroupId (int)

As an example, if Group 1 has two sub groups, Group 2 and Group 3, the Groups table would have 3 records

- Id - 1, Description - Group 1
- Id - 2, Description - Group 2
- Id - 3, Description - Group 3

The GroupChildren table will have 2 records

- Id - primary key id, GroupId - 1, ChildGroupId - 2
- Id - primary key id, GroupId - 1, ChildGroupId - 3

This links my two child groups to Group 1. I have two POCO classes to represent this which are as follow

```cs
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupChild> GroupChildren { get; set; }
}

public class GroupChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group ChildGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I have created mappers for both of these classes which are set up as follows

```cs
internal class GroupMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    internal GroupMapper()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsRequired();

        ToTable("Groups");
    }
}

internal class GroupChildMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<GroupChild>
{
    internal GroupChildMapper()
    {
        HasKey(g => g.Id);

        Property(g => g.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
        Property(g => g.GroupId).HasColumnName("GroupId").IsRequired();

        HasRequired(g => g.ChildGroup)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ChildGroupId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        ToTable("GroupChildren");
    }
}
```

To retrieve the group and sub groups I call

```cs
return GetDbSet<Group>()
    .Where(c => c.Id == id)
    .Single();
```

This returns the group with the Id and Description but I get the following error when looking at the GroupChildren property

> Invalid column name 'Group_Id'.
>   Invalid column name 'Group_Id'.

The column 'Group_Id' doesn't exist anywhere in code or the database. I've tried to resolve this by looking at other posts and some suggest that it's the way EF interprets primary/foreign key values but I cannot find how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Your model works when I try it in VS2012, EF5. There is a `Group_Id` column in `ChildGroup`. However, when I add a `Group` and add some `GroupChild` objects to it, I get "HierachyDb.GroupChildren' participate in the 'GroupChild_ChildGroup' relationship. 0 related 'GroupChild_ChildGroup_Target' were found. 1 'GroupChild_ChildGroup_Target' is expected." But before trying to fix it, let me ask: why not a simpe hierachy with one `Group` class with a `Groups` collection? Your model with intermittent classes is pretty clumsy for a hierarchy. And a child can be parent to its own parent!

Comment: Gert, thanks for your reply. Having looked at your response I have re factored my code to work in the simpler way you have suggested. We went down this road originally for one reason or another but in the end it has just added unnecessary complexity. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the `Invalid column name 'Group_Id'` error may be because you are overwriting the default column name for the foreign key by declaring `public int GroupId { get; set; }` in your `ChildGroup`.

Try removing `public int GroupId { get; set; }` from `ChildGroup`. The framework should take care of the relationship for you. Once you've done your data migrations to match your updated model, you should see that the framework has created a `Group_ID` column in your `Group` table, which sets up the relationship.